# StreamedResponse in Symfony4

Tags: reactjs, symfony, buffering

I want to buffer an audio(mp3) for and app made with React and Symfony4. The problem that I have is, when I inject the src in the Audio tag HTML5, I have to wait download is finished before playing the audio.

I guess, I have to send a StreamedResponse, instead of a Response. I want something like that http://opensource.box.com/spout/guides/symfony-stream-content-large-spreadsheet/ but in my case, always download the complete file, it is not buffered.

I did this code https://gitlab.com/nitsuga1986/media-buffer. You can check it here:
https://www.opoque.com/prueba/sample.html

And it is working well, but, if you check the code, the  tag has an index.php in the src, but as I am using Symfony 4, I cannot do that, I only could add in the src something like:

`<audio src="www.example.com/api/id_file=2" />`

I created a new route to get the file id, and inside this, I create a StreamedResponse, but as I said before, the file is download completely.

This is my controller method:

```
 /**
     * @Rest\Get("/v1/audio/{id}.{_format}", name="audio_download", 
     *
     * @SWG\Tag(name="Files")
     */
    public function downloadAudioAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $theme = [];
        $message = "";

                $response = new StreamedResponse();
                $response->setCallback(function () {
                    $handle = fopen($id, 'r');
                     while (!feof($handle)) {
                         $buffer = fread($handle, 1024);
                         echo $buffer;ob_flush();
                         flush();
                     }
                     fclose($handle);
                 });
                 $response->send();
   }
```

How could I add this feature to buffer an audio?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your Controller action-code, so we can better describe what to change?

Comment: I put in the next comment my controller. I only want to translate this https://gitlab.com/nitsuga1986/media-buffer to my controller and return an audio buffer

Comment: Please edit the question instead. Having edits as answers might confuse people and should be deleted.

Comment: What seems weird is that you don't return the response? Does this action even work? Are you sure this action is being used, maybe check with `bin/console router:match /api/id_file=2` and check if it uses the route you expect?

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to put the response.... effectively, I return the response with a $response->send();

Comment: Have you tried `return new BinaryFileResponse($filename);` instead? It will stream the file contents directly without having to specify a callback

Comment: I changed my controller with that:
`
$stream  = new Stream($fullName);
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($stream);

return $response;
`
But when I press to play the audio, it is download entirely, it is not streamed.

I try as well like this:
`
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($fullPath);
return $response;
`
And happens the same.

Answer (score 4):

I finally get the solution:

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($fullName);
                $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
                $response->setContentDisposition(
                    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
                    $filename
                );
                return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Symfony` has `File` helper to guess `Mime-Type` behind your file, and a `Stream` dedicated `class`. Give the path and the filename to them.

Example :

```php
new BinaryFileResponse(
    new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Stream($pathToFile),
    headers: ['Content-Disposition' => 'filename='.$filename]
)
```